# Add target blank to the return $original_url

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add `target_blank` to this function, but can't find how to do it:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'title_link_to_original_source', 10, 2 );
function title_link_to_original_source( $url, $post ) {
        //get the original url
        $original_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'original_source', true );
        //only imported post have orignial url, so we need to check
        if ( $original_url ) {
            return $original_url;
        }
    return $url;
}
```

this is the function that if provided and it works like it is but, i want it to open in a new tab. the goal is that the URl that is published has a target blank

If someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: the `$url` where you're trying to add `target_blank` is just a clear url without any html tag. you should be more detailed. add the details into your question( by editing it ): where you want to add `target_blank`( in the single posts some part, in the place, where you  're using some post(s) url and etc)? what is your goal?

Comment: hi thanks for the tip. the goal is that the $url that is printed that it has target _blank.